# issues with the changing the CSS for the Progress Bar step to step

Tags: html, css

I have issues with changing the CSS for the progress bar. Please review the attached image.

I would like to have the progress bar with all 10 values in one horizontal line.

I am including the script in to the html.

**CSS Script:**

```
  <style>
   @-webkit-keyframes myanimation {
  from {
    left: 0%;
  }
  to {
    left: 50%;
  }
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: #777;
}

.checkout-wrap {
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  margin: 40px auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.checkout-bar li {
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 14px 20px 14px 80px;
  position: relative;
}
ul.checkout-bar li:before {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 20px;
  line-height: 37px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  z-index: 999;
}
ul.checkout-bar li.active {
  color: #8bc53f;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul.checkout-bar li.active:before {
  background: #8bc53f;
  z-index: 99999;
}
ul.checkout-bar li.visited {
  background: #ECECEC;
  color: #57aed1;
  z-index: 99999;
}
ul.checkout-bar li.visited:before {
  background: #57aed1;
  z-index: 99999;
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(1):before {
  content: "1";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(2):before {
  content: "2";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(3):before {
  content: "3";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(4):before {
  content: "4";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(5):before {
  content: "5";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(6):before {
  content: "6";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(7):before {
  content: "7";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(8):before {
  content: "8";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(9):before {
  content: "9";
}
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(10):before {
  content: "10";
}

ul.checkout-bar a {
  color: #57aed1;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .checkout-bar li.active:after {
    -webkit-animation: myanimation 3s 0;
    background-size: 35px 35px;
    background-color: #8bc53f;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: "";
    height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  .checkout-wrap {
    margin: 80px auto;
  }

  ul.checkout-bar {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-size: 35px 35px;
    background-color: #EcEcEc;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ul.checkout-bar:before {
    background-size: 35px 35px;
    background-color: #57aed1;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 15px;
    content: " ";
    height: 15px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
  }
  ul.checkout-bar li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 50px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 19%;
  }
  ul.checkout-bar li:before {
    height: 45px;
    left: 40%;
    line-height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -65px;
    width: 45px;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  ul.checkout-bar li.visited {
    background: none;
  }
  ul.checkout-bar li.visited:after {
    background-size: 35px 35px;
    background-color: #57aed1;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: "";
    height: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
  }
}

   </style>
```

**HTML:**

```
</head>

  <body>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Caption:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>

<h1></h1>

<div class="checkout-wrap">
  <ul class="checkout-bar">

    <li class="visited first">
      <a href="#">Possible candidate</a>
    </li>

    <li class="previous visited">Forwarded to manager</li>

    <li class="previous visited">Phone screen</li>

    <li class="previous visited">Interview</li>

    <li class="previous visited">References</li>

    <li class="previous visited">Medical Assessment</li>

    <li class="previous visited">Backgroung Check</li>

    <li class="previous visited">Offer</li>

    <li class="previous visited">Hired</li>

    <li class="active">Declined Offer</li>

  </ul>
</div>    
  </body>
```

Alignment issue:

[image]

Comment: A fiddle to help any potential answerers debug: https://jsfiddle.net/54880cwc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reducing the width of `ul.checkout-bar li` within the `@media all and (min-width: 800px) {` media query. It's currently `19%` so you'll never get more than 5 on a row. Try `5%` instead, and add `vertical-align: top;` to the same selector.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yjz9Lzzg/

Comment: hi Dewd, I have an issue with the alignment of the text .i have applied the text to be centered by its not working. Please see the image in the question

Comment: @PraveenKumar Change the `left` property on the `ul.checkout-bar li::before` selector in the `@media all and (min-width: 800px) ` media query to something like `24%`.

Comment: Thanks Dewd.I have achieved the funcationality